# How to insert php variables from another file to a form with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

pls i'm trying to insert variable values from a php file into this html file using ajax but i don't know how to start here is the form

```
   <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>FULL NAME</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'fullname' id = 'fullname'></td>
                <td>CUID</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'idno' ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SURNAME</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'sname' id = 'sname'></td>
                <td>TITLE</td>
                <td>
                    <select name='title'>
                            <option>Select Title</option>
                            <?php
                                $conn = db();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare('select TITLE from titles order by TITLE');
                                $stmt->execute();
                                while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo "<option>".$data['TITLE']."</option>";
                                }

                            ?>
                        </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>FIRST NAME</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'fname' id = 'fname'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>MIDDLE NAME</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'mname' id = 'mname'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DESIGNATION</td>
                <td>
                    <select name='post' id ='post'>
                            <option>Select Post</option>
                            <?php
                                $conn = db();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare('select post from posts order by post');
                                $stmt->execute();
                                while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo "<option>".$data['post']."</option>";
                                }

                            ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>GENDER</td>
                <td>
                    <select name='gender'>
                            <option>Select Gender</option>
                            <?php
                                $conn = db();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare('select SEX from sx order by SEX');
                                $stmt->execute();
                                while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo "<option>".$data['SEX']."</option>";
                                }

                            ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>DATE OF RESUMPTION</td>
                <td><input type = 'date' name = 'dresume' id = 'dresume'></td>
                <td>CATEGORY</td>
                <td>
                    <select onchange='bn(this.value);' name='category'>
                            <option>Select Category</option>
                            <?php
                                $conn = db();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare('select CATEGORY from categories order by CATEGORY');
                                $stmt->execute();
                                while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo "<option>".$data['CATEGORY']."</option>";
                                }                               
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>DEPARTMENT</td>
                <td>
                    <select name='unit'>
                            <option>Select Department</option>
                            <?php
                                $conn = db();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare('select DEPARTMENT from units order by DEPARTMENT');
                                $stmt->execute();
                                while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo "<option>".$data['DEPARTMENT']."</option>";
                                }                               
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>UNIT</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'unit' id = 'unit'></td>
                <td>KOL</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'kol' id = 'kol'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LEVEL</td>
                <td>
                    <select name='level' >
                        <option>Select Level</option>
                        <?php
                            $conn = db();
                            $stmt=$conn->prepare('select level from levels');
                            $stmt->execute();
                            print_r ($stmt);
                            while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                echo "<option>".$data['level']."</option>";
                            }

                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>STEP</td>
                <td>
                    <select name='step'>
                            <option>Select Step</option>
                            <?php
                                $conn = db();
                                $stmt=$conn->prepare('select step from steps');
                                $stmt->execute();
                                print_r ($stmt);
                                while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
                                    echo "<option>".$data['step']."</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>SALARY SCALE</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'sscale' id = 'sscale'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>RESPONSIBLITY/DUTY POSY</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'dutypost' name = 'dutypost'></td>
                <td>RESPONSIBLITY ALOWANCE</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'rallowance' name = 'rallowance'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>SPECIAL PAYMENT</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'spayment' name = 'spayment'></td>
                <td>PAY PERCENTAGE</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'ppercent' name = 'ppercent'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>HOUSE DEDUCTION</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'hded' name = 'hded'></td>
                <td>RENT DEDUCTION</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'rded' name = 'rded'></td>
                <td>FURNITURE DEDUCTION</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'fded' name = 'fded'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>NHF</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'nhf' name = 'nhf'></td>
                <td>NHF_NO</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'nhfno' name = 'nhfno'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PFA</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'pfa' name = 'pfa'></td>
                <td>PFA_NO</td>
                <td><input type = 'text' id = 'pfano' name = 'pfano'></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

when an edit button is clicked these varibale will automatically appear in the form pls i'll need a head start at this still new at it thanks
here is the php file

```
    if(isset($_POST['edit'])) {
            $dresume  = $data['DRESUME'];
            $kol      = $data['KOL'];
            $level    = $data['LEVEL'];
            $step     = $data['STEP'];
            $dpost    = $data['DutyPost'];
            $dpay     = $data['DutyPay'];
            $spay     = $data['Special'];
            $ppercent = $data['Paypercent'];
            $rentd    = $data['HDEDP'];
            $house    = $data['HOUSE'];
            $furnided = $data['FURNIDED'];
            $nhf      = $data['NHF'];
            $nhfno    = $data['NHF_NO'];
            $pfa      = $data['PFA'];
            $pfano    = $data['PFA_NO'];
        }
```

Comment: where is your ajax attempt?

Comment: i dont know where to start fro with this one i just need a head start only

Comment: check at this site : https://webdesignerhut.com/pass-data-with-ajax-to-a-php-file/

Comment: mine is passing from php file to a form not the othe way round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic thing you should understand is that PHP executes only in server and you cannot execute your php script in html once the page is loaded.

Now you have a doubt that how did I get php written inside html worked?
Answer your file got parsed in the server and all php script written in between the "" executed and corresponding html is generated, See the source of your html in browser.

Once the page is served to browser your php code will not execute. To do any modification in the html loaded in browser, either you need to reload the page or you need some client script that executes in browser. Javascript can be used as a client script.

Ajax is a method of communication between your html loaded in browser and your server. ie, if you want to send some data to or from your html loaded in browser, you can make use of ajax. https://webdesignerhut.com/pass-data-with-ajax-to-a-php-file/ is a good example

You can find good and better documentations before you start

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a form HTML send parameters to an other PHP page.
If you want do it in ajax, you need to send the form anyway 
or put the ajax on the form page

form.html

```
<form method="post" action="success.php">
    <input type="text" name="id" />
</form>
```

success.php

```
<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>
```

That's the ajax way (on the same page)

form.html

```
<form method="post" id="formAjax" action="success.php">
    <input type="text" id="inputId" name="id" />
</form>

<script>
    $('#formAjax')on('submit', function() {
        var id = $('#inputId').val()
        alert('input id:'+id);
    }
</script
```